# Django: Hidden/Orphaned oneToOneField values

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

When I run in manage.py shell `qs = UserProfile.objects.all(); qs.count()` I get 18 instances. However, when I look at my webpage's admin, under UserProfile, I only see 6 users. I can loop through the users and print the full name`for i in qs: print(i.user.full_name)` it prints the first 6's full name and then errors out with this error: AttributeError: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute '_user_cache'

I think I have some (12) items in UserProfile that are not linked to a user profile. They don't show up in the admin and so I don't know how to delete them. Does anyone know how I can delete them from the command line or why they may be there in the first place? I'd like to not have orphaned items like these. Each one should relate to a user. It should at least show in the admin tab!

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user                = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete it like this:

```
# this command open the shell
python manage.py shell


# then import your model
from your_app.models import UserProfile

# then check command
# it must return 12
print(UserProfile.objects.filter(user_id__isnull=True).count())

# if print return 12 you should do it to delete user_profiles
UserProfile.objects.filter(user_id__isnull=True).delete()
```

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful to run the count first and then delete to make sure I was deleting the right things.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete these records using [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) filter. In command line run django shell:

```
>python manage.py shell
```

in in shell type follofing:

```
>from you_app_name.models import UserProfile

>UserProfile.objects.filter(user__isnull=True).delete()
```